# nullpointerexception while using if condition

Tags: spring, hibernate, criteria

im using hibernate criteria with spring(both annotation) im having `nullpointerexception`
this is my service class :

```
    public List<Voiture> rechercher_voiture(String type, String couleur,
         String lieuLocation) {
    List<Voiture> v = new ArrayList<Voiture>();
    Criteria crit;
    Session session = dao.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();


    crit = session.createCriteria(Voiture.class)
            .add(Restrictions.eq("type", type))
            .add(Restrictions.eq("lieuLocation", lieuLocation))
            .add(Restrictions.eq("statut", (long) 0));


        if(couleur.isEmpty()==false) {
            crit.add(Restrictions.eq("couleur", couleur));
        }
v = crit.list();

    return v;
}
```

the `nullpointerexception` is caused by the if condition any suggestion?

Comment: Maybe because couleur == null ?

Comment: null or not always error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens if `couleur = null`. Change it to `if(couleur!=null && couleur.isEmpty()==false)`